# Dynamic pipeline architecture in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, appdomain, pipeline

I am making a prototype for multitenant ASP.NET solution which will handle (in steps) the same types of messages for all tenants. However, for some tenants, some steps need to be handled slightly different.

So, let's assume for one message type, there are ten steps and we have 100 tenants. On average, a tenant has two custom steps. This gives ten standard step implementations and 20 custom.

What I am trying to achieve, is to be able to update the solution with an updated implementation (new DLL) of a step without having to restart the whole solution. So the question is - what is the best architecture to do this?

I have been thinking about having each step implementation run in it's separate AppDomain, but as the number of message types, tenants and steps increase, we'd get a lot of AppDomains which I guess will take a lot of memory and probably not give an optimal performance.

Is this the best/only approach, or is there another approach I should look into?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using MVC (or possibly even web forms) you could write your "steps" in inline Razor code.  Then just upload a new file when one of them needs to update.  IIS will pick up the change automatically without you needing to do anything.

Comment: I will consider that, but most of the steps aren't typically things you'd do in Razor code - they could include queries to the database or complex logic. So even if probably possible, it isn't the optimal solution in my mind.

Comment: Razor runs on the web server with full access to the database or any other resource you might need server-side and is executed in the same pipeline as controller code.  MVC (the separation of View and Controller) is simply a convention.  It would not be out of line for you to change the convention for this area of your application.  The world won't fall apart. :)  In this case you could think of MVC as a plugin architecture (eg. MEF) - which is exactly what you need.

Comment: I agree this is a way to go - it just doesn't quite sit right with me ;) I'll have a look at this approach, though. Perhaps it's better than I think :)

Comment: I understand.  I hope you find a solution that is both functional and pleasing to the mind!